# React-Native run-android: The expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I developed a React Native application and tested it using Expo. When I finished, I tried to export the apk but I saw that it crash immediately after the execution. Then I tried to run "react-native run-android" and I see that the problem was something about Expo. The exact error is:
"The expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo". How can I use this app without Expo? What should I do to make it work?

Comment: `react-native init` is run `react-native run` and `expo init` is run `expo start`

Comment: So if I want to generate an apk starting for an expo project what should I do? Because using assembleRelease the generated apk crashes immediately and I thought it was because of Expo.

Comment: If you created a project with Expo, run 'expo start' and run the simulator you ran to automatically generate apk.